# Why does pr2_plugs fail to locate my wall outlet?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get our PR2 to use the autonomous plugging action, and was able to get pr2_plugs_actions to run (using  app_plugin.py) but the /vision_outlet_detection node would consistenty fail to detect our wall outlets.  I looked at textured stereo images from Rviz and can verify that the outlet is in the images that the robot receives.  Is there anyway to look into what's going on with the detector more closely to see what's happening with it?  I tried changing the template from green_2x1white to white2x1hall, and fake_wall_2x1white_plug but none of these seems to work.

Has anyone else run into this problem?  We are running Electric on Ubuntu Lucid and our outlet is a 2x1 with the third prong on the bottom (shadowy side of outlet).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11464/why-does-pr2_plugs-fail-to-locate-my-wall-outlet?/) by [haidai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1020/haidai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The outlet detection code is only tested with the default template on outlets that look like the ones used here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_plugs. Does your outlet look the same? The detector only looks at the position of the holes, not the outlet cover.

Did you look at the output of rxconsole to see if there's any more feedback? Could you describe the behavior of the robot in more detail, that might give a better understanding of where in the state machine the robot got (did the projector turn on, did the robot align with the wall, did the robot succeed in finding the outlet from far away, ...).

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1